# openGL (GLUT) translate object with normals.

Tags: opengl, glut, normals

I'm translating my object with glTranslate to an other location. But the problem is that the normals stay at the old position. How can i translate them together with the object vertices.
I read about using the transpose of the inverse modelview matrix. But this is not working. It stretches out my whole model. I have left this code commented under need //translate normals

```
//Rotate model because Z axes is up 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(4, 4, 0.7);
glRotatef(90, 1.0, 0, 0);

//translate normals
//glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
//printMatrix(matrix);
//inverse(matrix, inverseM);
//transpose(inverseM);

//printMatrix(inverseM);
//glMultMatrixd(inverseM);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (int i = 0; i<triangles.size(); ++i)
{
    Vec3Df edge01 = vertices[triangles[i].v[1]].p - vertices[triangles[i].v[0]].p;
    Vec3Df edge02 = vertices[triangles[i].v[2]].p - vertices[triangles[i].v[0]].p;
    Vec3Df n = Vec3Df::crossProduct(edge01, edge02);
    n.normalize();
    glNormal3f(n[0], n[1], n[2]);
    for (int v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
        //color
        if (triangles[i].v[v] < meshColor.size()) {
            glColor3f(meshColor[triangles[i].v[v]].p[0], meshColor[triangles[i].v[v]].p[1], meshColor[triangles[i].v[v]].p[2]);
            glVertex3f(vertices[triangles[i].v[v]].p[0], vertices[triangles[i].v[v]].p[1], vertices[triangles[i].v[v]].p[2]);
        }
    }


}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Normals are not supposed to be translated. Normals are directions, not positions, so the whole notion of "translating" them makes no sense. The only useful thing to do with a normal is rotating it (and to a degree scale it, but not in the same way geometry is scaled).

Comment: So how can i move my object at still have the right normals? @datenwolf

Comment: As long as you're using the fixed function pipeline (i.e. no shaders) there's no need to do something with the normals at all. Fixed function OpenGL internally does the neccesary computations for normal transformation (i.e. just rotating and "counterskewing" when scaling). BTW: You should not re-compute normals upon each and every drawing iteration. Heck you shouldn't even use `glBegin`/`glNormal`/`glVertex`/`glEnd` at all, those functions are out of fashion for well over 20 years now. Use Vertex Arrays!